# issue with understanding dinic's algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, network-flow

I have a have a small miss understanding of dinic's algorithm about how it use the residual network

so the algorithm as far as i understand is the following

1- run bfs on the residual network and assign levels to the nodes based on the distance from the source

2- if the sink node was never reached terminate the algorithm

3- run dfs iterations going with strictly increasing levels to find augment paths until a blocking flow is reached and sum over all bottleneck values of the of the augment paths to get the maximum flow and update the residual network according to the bottlneck of each path

4- repeat 1 2 3

now my question is does this algorithm ever uses the backward edges of the residual network (the ones
that goes from v to u instead of u to v to cancel existing flow of the network) during dfs iterations?

because i usually represent residual edges this way:-

```
private static class ResidualEdge implements Comparable<ResidualEdge>{

        public int u, v;
        public long flow;
        public boolean reversed;
        public Edge originEdge;

        public ResidualEdge(int u, int v, long flow, boolean reversed, Edge originEdge) {

            this.u = u;
            this.v = v;
            this.flow = flow;
            this.reversed = reversed;
            this.originEdge = originEdge;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {


            if(obj == null || !(obj instanceof ResidualEdge))
                return false;

            ResidualEdge  edge = (ResidualEdge)obj;

            return edge.u == u && edge.v == v && edge.flow == flow && this.originEdge == edge.originEdge && this.reversed == edge.reversed;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {


            return Integer.hashCode((int) (flow + u + v + Boolean.hashCode(reversed)));
        }


        @Override
        public int compareTo(ResidualEdge o) {

            if(flow > o.flow)
                return 1;

            else if (flow < o.flow)
                return -1;

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

the originEdge being a reference to the original edge of the original network that the residual edge represent it's remaining capacity or flow to cancel to make it easier to update the original network

now I am asking this because if dinic's algorithm doesn't use reversed edges then I can just ignore representing reversed edges and the algorithm would be much simpler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it uses reversed edges.

Example:

[image]

Assuming that B->C edge will be processed before B->D edge, without reversed edges this algorithm will calculate that max flow is only 3, but in fact it is 4.

Usually in competitive programming when using Dinic's algorithm it's much easier to store graph not as edges, but as matrices NxN - first stores residual capacity of edge i->j, second stores flow through edge i->j. These matrices take O(N*N) memory, but Dinic's algorithm anyway runs in O(N*N*M), so when Dinic's algorithm can run fast enough, then the number of nodes is small enough so you can store matrices.

Comment: yes I understand but how do I store backward residual edges and be able to distinguish between them and between forward edges ? and how do I update them accordingly ?

Comment: You don't need to divide edges in forward and backward ones. Residual network contains two edges for each edge, and these two edges are same for algorithm.

Comment: Let `c[i][j]` be residual capacity of edge `i -> j` (by default it's 0). While you construct a graph, if you want to add edge `v -> u` with capacity `c0`, then you just increase `c[v][u]` by `c0`. During algorithm, if you want to increase flow of the edge `v -> u` by `f0`, then you decrease `c[v][u]` by `f0` and increase `c[u][v]` by `f0`. While you do BFS to find levels of each node, condition "there is an edge `v -> u` in residual network" is equal to `c[v][u] != 0`.

Comment: Please read https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/dinic.html, this implementation even stores edges as lists.